# Random set key is being cached?

Tags: reactjs, state, jsx

I am following a tutorial for React/Redux (https://youtu.be/WQMglp-JASk). This part of the tutorial adds a simple form to the page and adds each entry into another section. Here is the code for adding the new info to the page:

```
addNinja = (ninja) => {
    ninja.id = Math.random();
    let ninjas = [...this.state.ninjas, ninja];

    this.setState({
        ninjas: ninjas
    });
};
```

The `ninja` object is being passed to this method from this code:

```
state = {
    name: null,
    age:  null,
    belt: null
};

handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    });
};

handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.addNinja(this.state);
};

render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" onChange={this.handleChange}/>

                <label htmlFor="age">Age:</label>
                <input type="text" id="age" onChange={this.handleChange}/>

                <label htmlFor="belt">Belt:</label>
                <input type="text" id="belt" onChange={this.handleChange}/>

                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And the component JSX that is reused on submit:

```
<div className="ninja" key={ninja.id}>
    <div>Name: {ninja.name}</div>
    <div>Age: {ninja.age}</div>
    <div>Belt: {ninja.belt}</div>
    <button onClick={() => {deleteNinja(ninja.id)}}>x</button>
</div>
```

`ninja.id` is the key for the element being added.

The first submit works fine, any subsequent submits use the same key generated by `Math.random()` on the first submit. I also see the warning `Encountered two children with the same key` in the console for each subsequent submit.

When I console log the random number it is a different each time, but `ninja.id` is not being set to the new random number.

I assume caching is at play here but can someone please explain why this might be happening?

Comment: Can you show a running example somewhere like on Codepen? It's hard to tell how you display the content on submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I actually got this working myself but I would love for someone to tell me what the issue is.

To get it working, the `AddNinja` method should be:

```
addNinja = (ninja) => {
    let ninjas = [...this.state.ninjas, {
        "name": ninja.name,
        "age": ninja.age,
        "belt": ninja.belt,
        "id": Math.random()
    }];

    this.setState({
        ninjas: ninjas
    });
};
```

I have no idea why this works and the other version doesn't so any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Isn't that what I suggested?

Comment: Not quite. You are adding a new `Ninja` from the state, not from the form input. Your answer seems to be referring to a different scenario given that you thought I was mutating the state directly. I wrote this as if someone comes across the same issue as me, they would not get the code working from your answer alone

Comment: My code above is not adding a new Ninja from state. Where did you get this from? What you provided as a solution is exactly what I wrote above, I just didn't write the whole function for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the way you are adding the id for your ninja you are mutating your state which is a big no-no for react. So the following:

```
let ninjas = [...this.state.ninjas, ninja];
```

should be:

```
let ninjas = [...this.state.ninjas,
 {
 id: Math.random(),
 name: this.state.name,
 age: this.state.age,
 belt: this.state.belt
}
];
```

There are definitely better ways for using as id for iterating items within an array such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Comment: Thank Kleo. I am not modifying the state directly. The `ninja` variable is just the name, age and belt taken from the form, not the state. I am saving the current contents of the state in an array, creating a new `ninja` object from the form, assigning it a new, random ID, merging that into the array and the setting the state based on the new array